# Why Javascript doesn't let a function redefine itself from within itself?

Tags: javascript, scope, definition, redefinition

Consider the code:

```
    window.a = function(x){ 
        var r = x*2; 
        window.a =alert; // redefines itself after first call
        return r;
    }; 
    a('2 * 2 = '+a(2)); // doesn't work. it should've alerted "2 * 2 = 4"
```

This doesn't work either:

```
    window.a = function(x){ 
        alert(x); 
        window.a = function(x){ // redefines itself after first call
            var r = x*2; 
            return r;   
        }
    }; 
    a('2 * 2 = '+a(2)); // doesn't work. it should've alerted "2 * 2 = 4"
```

As neither does this:

```
    window.a = function(x){ alert(x); window.c = window.a; window.a = window.b; window.b = window.c; };
    window.b = function(x){ var r = x*2; window.c = window.b; window.b = window.a; window.a = window.c; return r; };
    a('2 * 2 = '+a(2)); // doesn't work.
```

And basically I've tried all possible ways and neither seem to do the job. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: just out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Well, the first one actually works for me (Chrome 18)

Comment: Works just fine in Chrome and IE...

Comment: As a general tip: try things out in the browser's JS console. If you do that, you'll quickly find that JS functions can do exactly what you want; you just have to do it in the right order. First evaluate `var r = a(2)`, and then `a('2 * 2 = ' + r)`

Comment: It's interesting that it works in Chrome. It shouldn't (see my answer), and doesn't in Firefox or Opera.

Comment: Funny how I drew my results based on testing in Chrome's console. It alerts 2 then alters 2+2=undefined. Damn...

It is pulled away from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936626/javascript-how-to-bandwagon-functions-and-change-their-purpose-after-each-call/9937382

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **are** successfully redefining the function, it's just that the expression calling it has already grabbed the old function reference: The first thing that happens in a call expression is that the thing defining what function to call is evaluated, see [Section 11.2.3](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.3) of the specification:

> **11.2.3 Function Calls**
>
> The production *CallExpression : MemberExpression Arguments* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *ref* be the result of evaluating *MemberExpression*.
> 2. Let *func* be GetValue(*ref*).
> 3. Let *argList* be the result of evaluating *Arguments*, producing an internal list of argument values (see 11.2.4).
> 4. If Type(*func*) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 5. If IsCallable(*func*) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> 6. If Type(*ref*) is Reference, then
>
>      a) If IsPropertyReference(*ref*) is true, then
>
>          i. Let *thisValue* be GetBase(*ref*).
>
>      b) Else, the base of *ref* is an Environment Record
>
>          i. Let *thisValue* be the result of calling the ImplicitThisValue concrete method of GetBase(*ref*).
> 7. Else, Type(*ref*) is not Reference.
>
>      a) Let *thisValue* be undefined.
> 8. Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method on *func*, providing *thisValue* as the this value and providing the list *argList* as the argument values.

Steps 1 and 2 occur before the function is redefined.

The solution is of course to make things happen in the order you expect ([live example](http://jsbin.com/oripoy) | [source](http://jsbin.com/oripoy/edit#html)):

```
window.a = function(x){ 
    var r = x*2; 
    window.a =alert; // redefines itself after first call
    return r;
}; 
var val = a(2);
a('2 * 2 = '+ val);
```

---

Side note: It's interesting that [your first example](http://jsbin.com/oripoy/2) works in Chrome (V8) (it also works in IE6's version of JScript; but then, JScript had **lots** of issues). It shouldn't work, and doesn't in Firefox (SpiderMonkey), Opera (Carakan), or IE9 (Chakra).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a strict left-to-right rule for order of evaluation of operator arguments. I am guessing that this includes the function-call operator, which means that the first `a` is evaluated before the expression.